# Entity Framework DbContext not in MVC project

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm just starting with Entity Framework in combination with .NET Core. I'm very suprised what i'm reading in guides. As far as i'm concerned database logic should not be in the Web project. This should be at least in a seperate Logic / Business project.

Yet i keep seeing things like this in the Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```

BloggingContext should not be known here.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Yes and no. It's using an IOC to achieve Dependency Inversion. Without it, your database layer now has control over how it gets a connection string for example, and how it resolves other dependencies.

Comment: Yeah i'm looking at how to get the connection string in the logic project now. Could you provide an example?

Comment: How you have it is the way to do it. I'm explaining that while inversion of control means in this case that your web project knows about the DBContext, it also means that you have control over how it's getting a connection string (As you have the "control" hence IOC)

Comment: Ok thanks. I did this now. Now i do have an followup question. How to retreive the BloggingContext at any other point then in the Controller? I still prefer to have my data logic nowhere near the Controller. Does this mean i have to pass the DbContext from the controller on as a parameter?

Comment: Injection is multi levels deep. You might inject a repository into your controller, and the repository has a constructor that requires the DBContext for example. Think of it like a tree (You will hear dependency tree come up a lot). It just spreads out and branches.

Comment: Maybe is useful https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1112848/Creating-Web-API-in-ASP-NET-Core

Comment: The example is from an App that uses the Identity system, I think that requires a 'hard' DbContext reference. In your controllers you can inject an interface (to a UoW for example, or to 1+ services). How (far) you want to mix and merge this with your BRL is up to you, without the Identity Fx the problem is entirely yours as well.